# Boolean algebra derivative - expression independent of the value of certain variable

Tags: derivatives, logic, partial-derivative, boolean-algebra

I'm given the following expression:

$I=((xw \implies (y \bar z)) \Leftrightarrow x \bar w)  \overline{(xy \bar z w)}$

This expression simplifies to $x \bar w \lor x \bar y \lor xz$.

Now, I know that an expression $f$ is independent from variable $x$ if: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$

The text of the exercise asks: **For which values of x,z does the expression I not depend on the variable y, but depend on the variable w**

**What I tried**:

I have that $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = xw(1 \oplus z) = 0$.

Now, this expression is false for all $x,w$ since it is a conjunction and $(1 \oplus z)$ is always negative, right? If so, is the answer to the first part of the question that it doesn't depend on $y$ for all values $x,z$?

As for the second question: I know that an expression is independent from a variable $x_i$ if the partial derivative of that expression by $x_i$ is $=0$. However, I know no way of determining *when the expression actually depends on the value*. Is it when the partial derivative $=1$?

Comment: For the first part $1\oplus z = \overline z$. For the second part of the question, "depend" is equivalent to "not independent" which is therefore $\frac{\partial I}{\partial w}\neq 0$ (so it must either be $1$ of depend on some other vars). BTW I have a hard time believing your derivative, indeed it should probably depend on $y$ right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton what do you think is wrong with my derivative? I used the definition of partial derivative of a logic function, for example: $f(x,y,z,w)$ for variable $y$ is $f(x,1,z,w) \oplus f(x,0,z,w)$.

Comment: From your second expression (which I did not check), I think we get $\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = (\overline w\lor\overline y\lor z)\oplus 0=\overline w\lor\overline y\lor z$ and $\frac{\partial I}{\partial w}=x\overline y\lor x z \oplus x\lor x\overline y\lor x z$

Comment: What is the definition of the derivative of a Boolean function? I've never encountered this notion before.

Comment: For those interested in the topic: [Boolean differential calculus](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Boolean_differential_calculus).

Comment: @AlexKruckman In short, for a boolean function $f(x,y)$, the boolean derivative for the variable $x$ is defined as $\partial_x f(x,y) = f(1,y) \oplus f(0,y)$. Same goes for variable y.

Now, the derivative of a boolean function w.r.t. a certain variable, is a new boolean function **independent of that variable**.